# High number of ethernet errors. Tool for testing the ethernet card?

Tags: networking

I have an Asus Sabertooth X79.

I often get corrupted files. I checked the RAM, but memtest finds no errors. To avoid the possibility of disk errors, I tried copying the files to tmpfs.

If I copy from the network, I get md5sum mismatches about once every 10 times using a 6Gb file.  Copying from RAM to RAM, I didn't get mismatches.

I get a very high number of errors in `ifconfig` (compared to others PCs I just took as reference, which have 0 with much more traffic).
Here is an example

```
RX packets:13972848 errors:200 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:101
```

The motherboard is new, but do you think there're some problems with it?
What could I use to test the (integrated) network adapter?
What else do you think I should double check?

--edit--

I tried another NIC, it gives a lot of Corrupted MAC on Input. 
Disconnecting: Packet corrupt
lost connection.
I noticed that another PC downloads at 11.1MB/s without problems.
This pc at 66.0 MB/s. Is there any way to try to limit the speed?

Comment: Might be better to ask this in Superuser of Server Fault?

Comment: Try to plug the computer in another switch/hub port. Did you try replacing the UTP cable? This can be caused by bad RJ-45 connectors. Also check the metallic contacts of your motherboard's female RJ-45 connector. Rusty contacts may cause packet loss.

Comment: I tried another NIC, it gives a lot of Corrupted MAC on Input. 
Disconnecting: Packet corrupt
lost connection.
I noticed that another PC downloads at 11.1MB/s without problems.
This pc at 66.0 MB/s. Is there any way to try to limit the speed?

Comment: ~12MB/s means a connection speed of 100Mbps. Your PC is connected at 1Gbps, which is more sensible to electric interference and cable/connector quality. Try `sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 autoneg off` to force a 100Mbps connection.

Comment: I would check cables, and switches too.

Comment: You're not plugged into a hub are you?

Comment: - what kind of modemcard is this exactly ? - sure not been replaced by an stolen one ?! (of social hackers or else ?!) - or the trouble lies simply at the provider in the server, where cable-thieves could be around (near next distributor of cables for whatever broadband-width or dsl-thiefes???) - ah, it is a PC not a notebook ?! - could then be, that pci-card of ethernet is not properly sticking in the pci-bus - only a little leaning set-in?!

Comment: Error#4309: user confused with the purpose of exclamation and question marks.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right tool with ifconfig - it is showing you the card packet errors.

You've tested correctly by trying another network card, and still getting errors, so eliminating card & driver issues.

So the problem is upstream - faulty switch or cable.

Keep swapping bits one at a time till you find the problem.